# ¿Cómo puedo digitar paréntesis “()” con el método SendKeys en C#?

Tags: c#

Estoy desarrollando un simulador web, y deseo digitar la ruta de un archivo utilizando el método :

> SendKeys.SendWait()

El problema es que esta ruta contiene paréntesis "()" y al colocar en el método `SendKeys.SendWait` el texto con paréntesis digita todo lo demás excepto los paréntesis.

Agradezco de antemano su gentil apoyo.

```
               if (tipoEvidencia.ToUpper() == "EI1")
               {
                   SendKeys.SendWait("D:\\CIERRES\\");
                   Thread.Sleep(850);
                   SendKeys.SendWait("Consumo(s) Registrado(s) - Nro  ");
                   Thread.Sleep(850);
                   SendKeys.SendWait(numdoc);
                   Thread.Sleep(850);
                   SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                   Thread.Sleep(2000);                                             
               }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes escribir los caracteres `(` y `)`, pero necesitas revisar la configuración de tu teclado, por ejemplo, en mi caso para escribir estos caracteres, tengo:

[image: CIERRES]

En este caso necesito usar:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> por lo tanto requiero: `+9` para escribir `(`
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> por lo tanto requiero: `+0` para escribir `)`

Ejemplo:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("+9");  // Escribe (   
SendKeys.SendWait("+0");  // Escribe )
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó perfecto!

Comment: Excelente, saludos! @Rafael39

Comment: Wow! no sabía que eso existiera. Excelente respuesta :)